# ServiceNow SOAP API close ticket with python

Tags: python, api, soap, soap-client, servicenow

I'm working on connecting a python script to a ServiceNow ticketing environment. Thankfully, ServiceNow has documentation on how to create a ticket from a python script, see documentation here:

http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Python_Web_Services_Client_Examples#gsc.tab=0

Here's the script I'm using to create a ticket:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from SOAPpy import SOAPProxy
import sys

def createincident(params_dict):

    # instance to send to
    instance='demo'

    # username/password
    username='itil'
    password='itil'


    # proxy - NOTE: ALWAYS use https://INSTANCE.service-now.com, not https://www.service-now.com/INSTANCE for web services URL from now on!
    proxy = 'https://%s:%s@%s.service-now.com/incident.do?SOAP' % (username, password, instance)
    namespace = 'http://www.service-now.com/'
    server = SOAPProxy(proxy, namespace)

    # uncomment these for LOTS of debugging output
    #server.config.dumpHeadersIn = 1
    #server.config.dumpHeadersOut = 1
    #server.config.dumpSOAPOut = 1
    #server.config.dumpSOAPIn = 1

    response = server.insert(impact=int(params_dict['impact']), urgency=int(params_dict['urgency']), priority=int(params_dict['priority']), category=params_dict['category'], location=params_dict['location'], caller_id=params_dict['user'], assignment_group=params_dict['assignment_group'], assigned_to=params_dict['assigned_to'], short_description=params_dict['short_description'], comments=params_dict['comments'])

    return response

values = {'impact': '1', 'urgency': '1', 'priority': '1', 'category': 'High',       
'location': 'San Diego', 'user': 'fred.luddy@yourcompany.com',  
'assignment_group': 'Technical Support', 'assigned_to': 'David Loo', 
'short_description': 'An incident created using python, SOAPpy, and web 
services.', 'comments': 'This a test making an incident with python.\nIsn\'t 
life wonderful?'}

new_incident_sysid=createincident(values)

print "Returned sysid: "+repr(new_incident_sysid)
```

However, I cannot find any good documentation on the process to resolve the ticket that I just created using the API. When I run the above script, I get the ticket number as well as the sys_id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently thats an old request, but i landed here searching, and apprently 400 other people too, so here is my solution :

Use the `server.update(sys_id="...",state="..",...)` to modify your record and set the right values to "resolve" it.

For this method only the `sys_id` parameter is mandatory, it's up to you for the other fields of your form.

P.S. : you can find the API here - https://.service-now.com/incident.do?WSDL